# Any way to stop notepad++ from tabbing entire subsequent lines of text when pressing tab?

Tags: notepad++

I recently downloaded notepad++ on this new laptop, everything's fine but the one issue is that when I press tab the current line as well all the lines of text below it will also indent. Is there some setting where I can set it so that only the current line the cursor is on indents and does not indent the other lines below. I tried messing around in Settings->Preferences->Tab Settings but no luck. Thank you for your time!

Comment: that doesn't happen for me.  Are you sure they are separate lines and on just a single really long line?  The line numbers on the left should tell you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To stop Notepad++ from auto-indenting new lines go to `Settings -> Preferences -> MISC.` and uncheck `Auto-indent`.

Tested in Notepad++ v6.4.5.