# In notepad++, can I disable multi-line tab indent (using word wrap)?

Tags: notepad++, indentation, word-wrap

On Notepad++ latest version.

For certain documents (or just globally if that's the only way) I want to disable the multi-line indent after a tab, if that line runs onto the next due to word wrap. So that only an indent shows at the first line. (Similar to Microsoft Notepad.)

```
Like this\n
   \t is what I want,
if you understand.

Not like this,\n
   \t which is the default
   behavior.
```

It must be a simple setting but I just can't find it.

I've tried various settings including Settings > Preferences > Auto-completion > Auto-indent. Also looked around the view menu.

Pictures to clarify (Sorry couldn't embed them do to newb restrictions):

[What I don't want, but which happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/upQA4.png)

[What I do want, as in Microsoft Notepad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xW54C.png)

---

A similar question did not have a solution for me:
[Any way to stop notepad++ from tabbing entire subsequent lines of text when pressing tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26372104/any-way-to-stop-notepad-from-tabbing-entire-subsequent-lines-of-text-when-pres?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

I found it, can't believe I overlooked it for so long.

Settings > Preferences > Editing > Line Wrap > Default